# Generating notation model from domain model

Tags: eclipse, model, emf, eclipse-gmf, qvt

I am currently working on a project that requires transforming one model to another model using qvto. The source model is state machine that is represented in tabular form. The target model is also statemachine that has nodes and edges. The source model has only domain meta-model, but the target model has both domain and notation meta-models. The notation meta-model is http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation. I transformed from source domain model to target domain model, but my target model has no notation model. What I wanted to do is to generate notation model from target model and serialize it to the same xmi file. I read documentation of EMF and GMF, and tried to do it but I couldn't. I also googled, that didn't help either. The header of the target model mentions both domain and notation meta-models. For clarity, look at the xmi file below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n1="http://www.target.com/EMF/1/SimpleStatechart" xmlns:notation="http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation">
  <n1:statemachine xmi:id="_QvItUPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" s_name="Sensor">
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_RzqFYPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" body="" from="_RNakwPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" to="_RzcqAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_BJd-wAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" body="in_ISensor:Activate/out_ISensor.send(sensorReply());" from="_RzcqAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" to="_7UnrQAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_DaWcQAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" body="in_InternalOptional:DetectedMovement/out_ISensor_NI.send(detectedMovement());" from="_7UnrQAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" to="_7Q_IcAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_EWLLUAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" body="in_ISensor:Deactivate/out_ISensor.send(sensorReply());" from="_7UnrQAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" to="_7OB7EAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_F9AmQAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" body="in_ISensor:Deactivate/out_ISensor.send(sensorReply());" from="_7Q_IcAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" to="_7OB7EAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
    <transitions xmi:type="n1:Transition" xmi:id="_GXe7wAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" body="in_InternalInevitable:Deactivated/&#xD;&#xA;out_ISensor_NI.send(deactivated());" from="_7OB7EAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" to="_RzcqAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
    <states xmi:type="n1:InitialState" xmi:id="_RNakwPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" name="InitialState"/>
    <states xmi:type="n1:BasicState" xmi:id="_RzcqAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" name="Deactivated"/>
    <states xmi:type="n1:BasicState" xmi:id="_7OB7EAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" name="Deactivating" internal=""/>
    <states xmi:type="n1:BasicState" xmi:id="_7Q_IcAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" name="Triggered"/>
    <states xmi:type="n1:BasicState" xmi:id="_7UnrQAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" name="Activated"/>
  </n1:statemachine>
  <notation:Diagram xmi:id="_QvItUfMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="ConformiqStateChart" element="_QvItUPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" measurementUnit="Pixel">
    <children xmi:type="notation:Node" xmi:id="_RNwjAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="2007" element="_RNakwPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RNxKEPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="5022"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:DescriptionStyle" xmi:id="_RNwjAfMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_YRV_NegaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:LineStyle" xmi:id="_RNwjA_MjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" lineColor="0"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_YRWmQegaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" x="496" y="57"/>
    </children>
    <children xmi:type="notation:Node" xmi:id="_RzhigPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="2012" element="_RzcqAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RziJkvMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="5017"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RziJk_MjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="5018"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RziJlPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="5019"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RziwoPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="7001">
        <styles xmi:type="notation:SortingStyle" xmi:id="_RziwofMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
        <styles xmi:type="notation:FilteringStyle" xmi:id="_RziwovMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:DescriptionStyle" xmi:id="_RzhigfMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_YRXNUOgaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:HintedDiagramLinkStyle" xmi:id="_RziJkPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_YRXNUugaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" x="420" y="192" width="225" height="109"/>
    </children>
    <children xmi:type="notation:Shape" xmi:id="_TAN_IPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="Note" fontName="Ubuntu" fontHeight="11" description="Describe the behavior of the&#xA;Sensor in this state machine." fillColor="0" transparency="0" lineColor="0" lineWidth="1">
      <children xmi:type="notation:BasicDecorationNode" xmi:id="_TARCcPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="DiagramName">
        <element xsi:nil="true"/>
      </children>
      <children xmi:type="notation:BasicDecorationNode" xmi:id="_TARpgPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="Description">
        <element xsi:nil="true"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:TextStyle" xmi:id="_TAN_IfMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:LineTypeStyle" xmi:id="_TAOmMPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
      <element xsi:nil="true"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_YRYbcOgaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" x="708" y="36" width="293" height="98"/>
    </children>
    <children xmi:type="notation:Node" xmi:id="_7OMTIAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="2012" element="_7OB7EAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7OOIUAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5017"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7OOIUQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5018"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7OOIUgetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5019"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7OOIUwetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="7001">
        <styles xmi:type="notation:SortingStyle" xmi:id="_7OOIVAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
        <styles xmi:type="notation:FilteringStyle" xmi:id="_7OOIVQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:DescriptionStyle" xmi:id="_7OMTIQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_7OMTIgetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:HintedDiagramLinkStyle" xmi:id="_7OMTIwetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_7OMTJAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" x="552" y="756" width="225" height="109"/>
    </children>
    <children xmi:type="notation:Node" xmi:id="_7RAWkAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="2012" element="_7Q_IcAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7RA9oAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5017"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7RA9oQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5018"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7RA9ogetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5019"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7RA9owetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="7001">
        <styles xmi:type="notation:SortingStyle" xmi:id="_7RA9pAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
        <styles xmi:type="notation:FilteringStyle" xmi:id="_7RA9pQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:DescriptionStyle" xmi:id="_7RAWkQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_7RAWkgetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:HintedDiagramLinkStyle" xmi:id="_7RAWkwetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_7RAWlAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" x="324" y="588" width="225" height="109"/>
    </children>
    <children xmi:type="notation:Node" xmi:id="_7Uo5YAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="2012" element="_7UnrQAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7Uo5ZQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5017"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7UpgcAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5018"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7UpgcQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="5019"/>
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_7UpgcgetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="7001">
        <styles xmi:type="notation:SortingStyle" xmi:id="_7UpgcwetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
        <styles xmi:type="notation:FilteringStyle" xmi:id="_7UpgdAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:DescriptionStyle" xmi:id="_7Uo5YQetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_7Uo5YgetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:HintedDiagramLinkStyle" xmi:id="_7Uo5YwetEeaf_-AtraPkfA"/>
      <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_7Uo5ZAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" x="264" y="384" width="225" height="109"/>
    </children>
    <styles xmi:type="notation:DiagramStyle" xmi:id="_QvItUvMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q"/>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_Rzr6kPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="4002" element="_RzqFYPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" source="_RNwjAPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" target="_RzhigPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_RzshoPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_RzshofMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" x="19" y="-12"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_X39ZA9krEeSNSYp_vqikKg" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_YRX0YugaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_YRX0Y-gaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" points="[0, 0, 0, -94]$[0, 94, 0, 0]"/>
      <sourceAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_53a-Yfi3EeSDRc6--mGWrg" id="(0.48,1.0)"/>
      <targetAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_YRX0ZOgaEeSg-pTEoxDT6g" id="(0.5,0.0)"/>
    </edges>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_BJkFYAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="4002" element="_BJd-wAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" source="_RzhigPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q" target="_7Uo5YAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_BJkscAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_BJkscQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" x="-3" y="24"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_BJkFYQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_BJkFYgeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_BJkFYweuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" points="[-39, 35, 117, -137]$[-159, 118, -3, -54]"/>
      <sourceAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_BJnIsAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.17777777777777778,0.6788990825688074)"/>
    </edges>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_DaXDUAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="4002" element="_DaWcQAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" source="_7Uo5YAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" target="_7RAWkAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_DaXqYAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_DaXqYQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" x="29" y="6"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_DaXDUQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_DaXDUgeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_DaXDUweuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" points="[4, 22, 17, -161]$[65, 129, 78, -54]"/>
      <sourceAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_DaY4gAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.5555555555555556,0.7981651376146789)"/>
    </edges>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_EWLyYAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="4002" element="_EWLLUAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" source="_7Uo5YAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" target="_7OMTIAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_EWLyZAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_EWLyZQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" y="40"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_EWLyYQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_EWLyYgeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_EWLyYweuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" points="[27, 27, -323, -315]$[335, 351, -15, 9]"/>
      <sourceAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_EWNnkAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.10666666666666667,0.7522935779816514)"/>
      <targetAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_EWOOoAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.1688888888888889,0.9174311926605505)"/>
    </edges>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_F9BNUAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="4002" element="_F9AmQAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" source="_7RAWkAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" target="_7OMTIAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_F9B0YAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_F9B0YQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" y="40"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_F9BNUQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_F9BNUgeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_F9BNUweuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" points="[54, 21, -125, -49]$[165, 67, -14, -3]"/>
      <sourceAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_F9DpkAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.76,0.6605504587155964)"/>
      <targetAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_F9DpkQeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.06222222222222222,0.3119266055045872)"/>
    </edges>
    <edges xmi:type="notation:Edge" xmi:id="_GXfi0AeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="4002" element="_GXe7wAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" source="_7OMTIAetEeaf_-AtraPkfA" target="_RzhigPMjEeS6mNxtIz5_4Q">
      <children xmi:type="notation:DecorationNode" xmi:id="_GXfi1AeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" type="6002">
        <layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Location" xmi:id="_GXfi1QeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" y="40"/>
      </children>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:RoutingStyle" xmi:id="_GXfi0QeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" routing="Rectilinear"/>
      <styles xmi:type="notation:FontStyle" xmi:id="_GXfi0geuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" fontName="Segoe UI"/>
      <bendpoints xmi:type="notation:RelativeBendpoints" xmi:id="_GXfi0weuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" points="[-10, -54, 76, 427]$[-74, -461, 12, 20]"/>
      <targetAnchor xmi:type="notation:IdentityAnchor" xmi:id="_GXhYAAeuEeaf_-AtraPkfA" id="(0.5955555555555555,0.8165137614678899)"/>
    </edges>
  </notation:Diagram>
</xmi:XMI>
```

From the transformation, I have the top part of the target model until  n1:statemachine, which is the domain model. From n1:statemachine, on wards the graphical representation of the upper part continues which I want to generate. 
How can I generate the notation model for the domain model that I get from model transformation?

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the EMF resource handling of QVT, but I try to do my best to describe what needs to be done on an EMF- and GMF level.

Technically, the notation model is the same kind of EMF model than the domain model you already successfully generate, just it conforms to another metamodel called `http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/runtime/1.0.2/notation` and available from the corresponding GMF plug-in `org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.notation`.

You have to make your transformation aware of this metamodel, then you can generate its instances similarly to the original model. The transformation needs to connect the notation model with the target domain model elements based on the definition of the notation model; but that is the same kind of crossreference handling your domain model already supports.

Finally, in order for you to have both the target and the notation model serialized into the same xmi file, you have to add both to the same EMF resource, something along the following:

```
EObject targetDomain = ...; //root element of the target domain model
EObject targetNotation = ...; //root element of the target notation model
EList<EObject> contents = targetResource.getContents();
contents.add(targetDomain);
contents.add(targetNotation);
```

These steps together should allow you to generate the notation model accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. It is very helpful. would you mind elaborating on the third paragraph? "The transformation needs to connect the notation model with the target domain model elements based on the definition of the notation model; but that is the same kind of cross reference handling your domain model already supports." I don't understand especially the but part.

Comment: I meant, the notation metamodel defines references (sorry, I don't know exactly which) that you have to fill out in your transformation for the notation model to be displayable.